# Is it possible to read the memory of a running java application?

Tags: java, memory, jvm

I'd like to learn how, or if its possible at all to programmaticly interact with a black-box java application(by reading its data).   Has there been any previous research/work on doing this sort of thing?

I'd imagine that running on a JVM significantly complicates things.

@anon: Doing this with any JVM is relevant.  Do you have to know or control the specifics of how the JVM allocates memory to extract data from a java application?

Comment: Running on an arbitrary JVM, or a particular commercial JVM, or on a JVM you've developed especially for this purpose?

Running on a virtual machine instead of a real one makes things *easier* if you control the VM internals, and even if you don't, it doesn't make it any harder as long as you know what those internals are.

Comment: A related thread that should apply here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771868/can-i-access-object-from-another-jvms-memory-without-requesting-that-jvm

Comment: Maybe the debugger interface helps http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/guide/jpda/jvmdi-spec.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could look into [java.lang.instrument](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html). As long as you understand the class structure of the application, it will let you modify the methods in an already-running JVM and you may be able to concoct a way that allows you to extract or insert data enough to communicate (depends on the methods available, of course).

Comment: Thanks, I had never heard of this and it looks promising.  I imagine using it in conjunction with the profiling tools other answers have mentioned could be helpful as well.

Answer (score 1):

The [Sable](http://www.sable.mcgill.ca/) group at McGill University has contributed a lot of research to the Java world.

Much of the work is getting rather dated, but you might find some help in their [EVolve](http://www.sable.mcgill.ca/evolve/) project which has the goal of visualizing object-oriented programs.  Some of their projects appear to be actively maintained (such as [Soot](http://www.sable.mcgill.ca/soot/), their Java optimization framework), so you might find luck contacting them directly

Answer (score 1):

It is easily possible with, for example, [StackTrace](http://www.adaptj.com/main/stacktrace). It can attach to a java process and let you inspect and change almost everything with BeanShell.

Comment: Looks like that link is broken?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is what the [Eclipse MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) does. You might want to take a look at the source code...

Answer (score 0):

The HotSpot JVM allows you to hook up an agentlib from a profiler (see [Open Source Java Profilers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948549/open-source-java-profilers) or commercials like [Your Kit](http://www.yourkit.com/)), in the profiler you can then inspect the memory/cpu/threads etc. 
If you want very specific stuff you might want to make your own agentlib that sends you information about the jvm that you need.